# Evaluate symfun

Tags: matlab, function, ode

I am evaluating `y(za)` using ODE. Now with the code mentioned below, I am able to get the expression/equation of `y` in terms of `za`. But I want the `y` value at `za` and I am not sure how I can evaluate it. Whenever I try to evaluate the definite value of the `y`, I again get the expression, also I have no idea how I can use it in further calculations. Here is a sample of what I am doing.

```
c=0.0371;
A=1.8364e-6;
B=3.9147e-8;
C=1.7719;
za=2.5e-4;

syms y(za)
ode = diff(y,za)== (1/B)*((y*(A))-N_h2);
cond = y(0)== y0h2_a;
ySol(za) = dsolve(ode,cond);
subs(ode,y(za),za)
double(ans)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to evaluate the solution `ySol`.

Comment: At least the variables `N_h2` and `y0h2_a` are missing to reproduce your issue. I have problems understanding what you want to do. In the line `ySol...` you get something like `ySol(za)=42*za` Taking that simpler example, what is the next step you want to achieve?

Comment: @LutzLehmann, it returns the same expression rather than a value.

Comment: @Daniel, I am trying to solve the Stefan-Maxwell diffusion equation and the next step would be to calculate the spacial mass balance. So I need to evaluate `y` at `za` which should return a value in-between `y(za)`= 0 to 0.995. The `N_h2` value can be taken as `1e-6` and `y0H2_a` as `0.995`.

Comment: You urgently need to separate symbolic variables from floating point variables. It seems that with `syms y(za)`, `za` was overwritten with a symbolic variable as well. Replace `syms z, y(z)` and try again.